# Paginação de mysqli para PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Boa tarde, estou a tentar desenvolver um sistema de páginação para as minhas tabelas, e já tinha um código em mysqli então decidi aproveitar, mas tive de alterar para pdo e não funciona.

O código até agora mostra o número de página correto consoante o número de utilizadores que tenho e também da varíavel 
$qnt_result_pg = 2;
 o problema é ao clicar para mudar de página que não acontece nada simplesmente no link do site muda para a página que selecionei.
    //Setar a quantidade de itens por pagina
    $qnt_result_pg = 2;

```
//calcular o inicio visualização
$inicio = ($qnt_result_pg * $pagina) - $qnt_result_pg;

//paginação
$result_pg = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num_result FROM utilizador";
$stm2 =$pdo->prepare($result_pg);
$stm2->execute();
$row_pg = $stm2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//Quantidade de pagina 
$quantidade_pg = ceil($row_pg['num_result'] / $qnt_result_pg);
//Limitar os link antes depois
$max_links = 10;
//mostrar paginação
echo "<div>";
echo "<a href='adminuti.php?pagina=1'>Primeira</a> ";

for($pag_ant = $pagina - $max_links; $pag_ant <= $pagina - 1; $pag_ant++){
if($pag_ant >= 1){
echo "<a href='adminuti.php?pagina=$pag_ant'>$pag_ant</a> ";
}
}

echo "<a><span style=color:orange> | $pagina | </span></a> ";

for($pag_dep = $pagina + 1; $pag_dep <= $pagina + $max_links; $pag_dep++){
if($pag_dep <= $quantidade_pg){
echo "<a href='adminuti.php?pagina=$pag_dep'>$pag_dep</a> ";
}
}
echo "<a href='adminuti.php?pagina=$quantidade_pg'>Ultima</a>";
echo "</div>";
```

Basicamente as alterações que fiz foi de

```
   $result_pg = "SELECT COUNT(idp) AS num_result FROM partituras2";
   $resultado_pg = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $result_pg);
   $row_pg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_pg);
```

passei para

```
$result_pg = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num_result FROM utilizador";
$stm2 =$pdo->prepare($result_pg);
$stm2->execute();
$row_pg = $stm2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```